# Convert this list of lists in CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

I am a novice in Python, and after several searches about how to convert my list of lists into a CSV file, I didn't find how to correct my issue.

Here is my code :

```
#!C:\Python27\read_and_convert_txt.py
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':

with open('c:/python27/mytxt.txt',"r") as t:
    lines = t.readlines()
    list = [ line.split() for line in lines ]

with open('c:/python27/myfile.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for sublist in list:
        writer.writerow(sublist)
```

The first `open()` will create a list of lists from the txt file like

```
list = [["hello","world"], ["my","name","is","bob"], .... , ["good","morning"]]
```

then the second part will write the list of lists into a csv file but only in the first column.

What I need is from this list of lists to write it into a csv file like this :

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4 ......
hello     world      
my        name      is        bob
good      morning
```

To resume when I open the csv file with the txtpad:

```
hello;world
my;name;is;bob
good;morning
```

Comment: strange as default separator is comma, not semicolon. But whatever: can you try: `writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\t")`

Comment: note: use `writer.writerows(list)` directly. And don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: This can't be your actual indentation. This won't run. Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this is what you want:

```
list = [["hello","world"], ["my","name","is","bob"] , ["good","morning"]]
with open("d:/test.csv","w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerows(list)
```

Gives as output file:

```
hello;world
my;name;is;bob
good;morning
```

Comment: Hello Bart, it works but i don't know why there is a blank line between each line. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

Simply use pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

By default missing values will be filled in with None to replace None use

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

So your final code should be like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Cheers!!!

Note: You should not use list as a variable name as it is a keyword in python.